# Using React-Native with a Web Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have installed Expo XDE, and created a new project `funproject`. I understand that the XDE is meant for devices and I could connect my virtual devices.

However, I would also like to reuse the same code base for a web application.

I have broused to the location on my localhost where the app should be.

> http://localhost:19001/

This looks right, I can see the index.html page. It's actual file path is.

> funproject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\middleware\index.html

Here are the contents of the `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>React Native</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>React Native packager is running.</p>
  <p><a href="http://facebook.github.io/react-native/">Visit documentation</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

So I added a div for the content and the script, app.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>React Native</title>
</head>
<div id="content"></div>
<body>
  <p>React Native packager is running.</p>
  <p><a href="http://facebook.github.io/react-native/">Visit documentation</a></p>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app.js"></script>
```

I am new to react, but the idea that I can target web, and mobile all in one, is very enticing. Unfortunately this does not work! When I use chrome developer tools, I am getting this error for line 1 of app.js

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import                      app.js:1

Here is the default generated app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Could the person who downvoted, care to share why?

Answer (score 1):

You had it mostly wrong, actually -- all wrong.

Let's start with;

> However, I would also like to reuse the same code base for a web application.

So this is wrong, the project you are working on is a native project, which uses the component based rendering logic of react, and produces real legit native ui elements for android or iOS.

Even though you are still using "react" this does not mean you can reuse the app in your browser.

The local server that started in a development interface, or a package delivery and update system (**packager**) for your phone or simulator (in order to access it via wifi network).

That server and the context of it is just a development tool for you.

> You should first understand the logic behind tech you are using; https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: "same code base" does not equal all the code. There are in fact many projects that separate out the business logic from the display logic. I wen't with those approaches. And now I have learned a lot more about `npm`. But you are right, this was all wrong. I wasn't even using `react` right by itself. I started following this project. http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/